# Möbius strip is non-orientable from Gallot's "Riemannian Geometry"

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, mobius-band

I was working on the proof that Möbius strip is non-orientable using the following definition:

A manifold $M$ is called orientable, if there exist a smooth atlas $(U_i, \phi_i)_{i \in I}$ such that

$$\det(J(\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1}))> 0 \quad\text{for all}\quad i, j \in I.$$

After a couple of fails I tried to understand the proof from Riemannian Geometry by Sylvestre Gallot. He defines the following two charts on the Möbius strip $M$:

$(U_1, \phi_1)$ with $U_1 = \big( (0, 1) \times \mathbb{R} \big)/\sim$ and $\phi_1(x, y) = (x, y)$

and

$(U_2, \phi_2)$ with $U_2 = \big([0, \frac{1}{2}) \cup (\frac{1}{2}, 1] \times \mathbb{R}\big)/\sim$ and $\phi_2(x, y) =  \begin{cases} 
   (x, y), & \text{if } x > \frac{1}{2} \\
   (x+1, -y), & \text{if } x < \frac{1}{2}
  \end{cases}$

where $(0, y) \sim (1, -y)$.

Here comes the proof from the book:

[image: Proof from Gallot]

I tried to follow the proof, but I don‘t get, why should $g_j \circ \phi_1^{-1}$ (and also  $g_j \circ \phi_2^{-1}$) be differentiable or at least why their partial derivatives for Jacobian exist? I don’t see any connection between $\phi_1, \phi_2$ and the atlas $(W_j, g_j)_{j \in J}$.

Comment: These are all charts compatible with the structure of $M$ as a differentiable manifold.

Comment: @TedShifrin, but how do I know that these two atlases belong to the same differential structure? I‘ve googled that the Möbius strip do have just one differential structure, but it‘s not what I know at this point of the proof and it wasn‘t discussed in the book either.

Comment: The point is that when one talks about a differentiable manifold, one knows that it comes equipped with a differentiable structure (which is a maximal atlas ...). When we talk about charts on that manifold, we *only* allow charts that are in the maximal atlas.

Comment: @TedShifrin, but in this case the proof above shows that the Möbius strip equipped with the differential structure, which contains $\phi_1, \phi_2$ is not orientable. How could I know, that there is no other possible differential structure, which do not contains $\phi_1, \phi_2$, such that Möbius strip could be orientable? And in general case: how different are the differential structures of a smooth manifolds? Is there a manifold that is orientable with one differential structure, but non-orientable with the other one?

Comment: Your final question is the right question to ask. And the answer is that orientability, in fact, depends only on the underlying *topological* structure, and not on the differentiable structure. But you need algebraic topology to discuss that point. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin, thank you for your help! Oh, then I think I have to look for this topic in algebraic topology next. :)